# Accessing Parameters mapped by @RequestMapping for Tracing

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am currently working on a monitoring application using Spring Cloud Sleuth. Currently I try to collect as much information about my requests as possible.

To keep the approach as scalable as possible I use `GenericFilterBeans` and `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` to access information from the requests sent to the REST-API.

I am struggling with getting parameters of a REST-call where the parameters are mapped from the URL like in the following code snippet:

```
  @RequestMapping(
            value = {"/{service}/{route_id}/book", "/accounting-core-service/{service}/{route_id}/book"},
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView book(@PathVariable(value="service") String serviceName,
                             @PathVariable(value = "route_id") int routeId,
                             HttpServletResponse response) {
    /*Do something*/
}
```

The question is not, whether it is good practice or not to write it like so. The question is whether there is an approach similar to Filter or Interceptor (or the proper use of them) to access those parameters.

A requirement is, that it can be applied easily to an application by adding very few lines of code. Annotating every Method call manually or manually inserting the code to write the parameters into the trace from within the method is not feasible for me.

If you need more information feel free to ask. I will provide you with all information you need to help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not officially supported (as it's not written in the reference documentation), Spring MVC holds that information as request attributes.

You could create your own `HandlerInterceptor`, ordered right after the Sleuth one, and get that information from the request like this:

```
// "/{service}/{route_id}/book"
String matchingPattern = (String) request
                    .getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
// "service" => "fooService", "route_id" => "42"
Map<String, String> templateVariables = (Map<String, String>) request
                    .getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
```

Note, the template variables are already decoded at that point, which is probably what you want anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for that solution. Just out of curiosity: What is the reason why this does not work in GenericFilterBean? I would assume that I have the same request there. But testing it showed no results for the params. Any idea?

Comment: Being a plain Servlet Filter, I guess it's being applied before the handler mapping takes place (before we know that this request should be handled by a Spring MVC handler), so that information is not yet available. Such a request could be handled by another Servlet, the static resource handling provided by the servlet container, another Servlet filter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Filter that intercept all the requests.

For each request you can retrieve also this informations:

- query parameters
- body of request
- url
- header parameters

You can save all this data as you need.
This is the best way you can do that.

---

If you need to group all urls like `/{service}/{route_id}/book` in a "family" of urls you can do that splitting the url and check if it is part of the family, but when a new family is added in your code you need to update the filter (or configure something in an external file or database).

Comment: I already do filter for the request. And the parameters in `request.getParameterMap()` can be easily extracted. However I need a somewhat generic way to access those mapped parameters. Am I getting you right, that there is no way beside getting every endpoint URL pattern in the API and then add a manual mapping logic in the filter that is applied to the URL that comes with any request?